# Extracting values from Solidity events via Ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js

I've seen similar questions here with explanations, but can't quite make this work.

Using ethers.js, I have a function that makes a transaction on the smart contract. I am listening to an event below to extract a parameter, but then outside of the Promise it is `undefined`:

```
let orderHash;
myContract.on("MakeOrder", (order, hash) => {
  orderHash = hash;
});

console.log(orderHash) // logs undefined
```

How to properly extract the value?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this working code:

```
const makeOrderEvent = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  myContract.on("MakeOrder", (order, hash, event) => {
    event.removeListener();

    resolve({
      order: order,
      hash: hash,
    });
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    reject(new Error("timeout"));
  }, 60000);
});

const event = await makeOrderEvent;
console.log(event);
```